# ASP.NET appDomainResourceMonitoring Counters Returning No Data

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, appdomain, perfmon

I have configured ASP.NET app domain resource monitoring as per this blog post:

http://www.shubho.net/2011/02/performance-monitoring-aspnet.html

Everything seems to be as expected, except that I get no data for the following counters (via perfmon):

```
\ASP.NET Application(__Total)\% Managed Processor Time (estimated)
\ASP.NET Application(__Total)\% Managed Memory Used (estimated)

\ASP.NET Application(_LM_W3SVC_2_ROOT)\% Managed Processor Time (estimated)
\ASP.NET Application(_LM_W3SVC_2_ROOT)\% Managed Memory Used (estimated)
```

(They always show 0.0, even though all the other counters in \ASP.NET Application\ work).

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: IIS6, IIS7? I am guessing IIS7, but you need to be quite specific when asking these types of questions.

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but is there actually an ASP.NET application running on your server?

Comment: I am experience the exact same thing.  Did you ever find out why?

Comment: @pksorensen Haven't yet.

Comment: @Kev IIS7.5. Yes, an app is 'running' (I am making requests to it).

Comment: Perfmon also just shows 0 when logged in on the machine. I started developing perf counters against the w3wp processes instead

Comment: @pksorensen are you running on Win7 as well? My next step was to try this on a Windows Server install, in case it had something to do with OS version?

Comment: I am on production server. 2012 R2.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `appDomainResourceMonitoring` parameter not only to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config`, but to the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` as well. It helped me:
[image]